# How to grep files that groups have permissions for?

Tags: linux, bash

```
ls -l | grep -El '.....w'
```

The output is always like (standard input).

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern matches any part of a line that has 5 characters `.....` and a `w`, for example:

```
-rwxrwxr-x
-rwxrwxrwx
```

So you have to add the anchor `^` to the pattern to tell `grep` to match only from the beginning of the line:

```bsh
ls -l | grep '^.....w'
```

---

The option `-l` doesn't need necessary in your case since you are not grepping a file but the *(standard input)*, from `man grep`:

> -l, --files-with-matches
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop  on  the  first
> match.

The option `-E` doesn't seem necessary either:

> -E, --extended-regexp
> Interpret PATTERNS as extended regular expressions (EREs, see below).

but you are not using any extended regex.

Comment: thanks! That really helps